# Find the Exact Frame of a rotated SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, rotation, frame, skspritenode

I really want to know how to find the EXACT frame of an `SKSpriteNode` if it is rotated. Currently, the frame of an `SKSpriteNode` looks like this:

[image: ]]

This frame is the `rect.frame`.

However, this frame includes a lot of empty space due to its `zRotation`. I don't want this empty space and instead want the frame of exactly the `SKSpriteNode`. 
This is what I want:

[image]

How can I achieve this? If you have any idea how to find this 'exact' frame of an `SKSpriteNode`, I would really like to know. Please use ***SWIFT***.

Thank you

Comment: You don't, CGRect is x y width height, not x1 y1 x2 y2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done.

Put a dummy node at the bottom left of your sprite that you know the exact size of. Probably use a perfect square. Anchor it's bottom left to the bottom left of your parent. The parent is the one you want the exact size definition of.

From there, two ways:

1. Scale the dummy sprite to the size of the sprite you're curious about, and use those measurements to determine where the sprite is and what size it is at any point in time.
2. Put another dummy sprite at the top right of the parent. In this case you can use the midpoint of your two dummy objects, you don't need to use their edges perfectly. Now you can find the position of these two dummies, at any time, and figure out the size/shape/outline of your sprite in world space units.

---

*Here's way 1 animated*

[image]

Comment: Excellent idea. 2 sounds easier and I would suggest: instead of dummy sprites, use SKNodes (which have position but no content) and make them child nodes of the target Sprite to constrain them to the bottom left and top right respectively.

Comment: @Confused I just don't see how this would work - the dummy sprite itself will have an `accumulatedFrame`, which will just be another unrotated frame around the rotated dummy.

Comment: which one? @Tim

Comment: @Confused Which what? I simply don't see how you could end up with any sprite whose frame isn't a standard square as pictured in the question.

Comment: @Tim there are two different ways suggested. There's probably many others. Which part are you struggling with, and what are you, in particular, trying to do that doesn't work using this methodology?

Comment: @Tim if you need code for this, you're going to have to do it yourself. Scaled sprites have their own size in their local coordinates. You can then add rotation to it to get the exact frame in game/world space.